# GUI text editor with syntax highlighting + background text highlighting

Tags: text, syntax, editor, highlighting

Looking for a GUI based text editor that has syntax highlighting for some of the more commonly used languages, plus manual text backround highlighting.  Like you can permanently highlight selections of text, not just 'current line highlighting' or changing the default background color for 'currently selected' text.  I thought notepad++ had this, but I haven't been able to tell how to access it if so.

I've only been able to find editors that do one or the other so far.  Mostly just want this for studying purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at AvalonEdit from the SharpDevelop project. Might be what you're looking for. Or at least a good basis to develop your own.